# marionette 3.0 module ?? webpack

Tags: backbone.js, webpack, marionette.js

Доброго времени суток.
Я новичек в webpack и marionette.
Можно сказать начал изучение его с версии 3.0.
Так вот меня интересует возможность реализации модулей в системе.
Вот что я нашел в документации к marionette 3.0 - удалены модули. Нужно использовать webpack и его сервисы.
Не могли бы вы кинуть пару примеров на реализацию модулей и их подгрузку ?

> Marionette Modules have been completely removed in favor of using the
>   more standard JavaScript module loaders e.g. Webpack or Browserify.

Comment: http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html

Comment: Это про то, что это за модули и с чем они едят. А настрйока вебпака ничем не отличается от настройки вебпака для того же реакта или чего угодно